# how to add options in <select> tag at page load dynamically using c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax

I am populating cascaded `<select>` elements from a database using jQuery ajax. There is just one problem: I am unable to add the default "select program" option at the top to my first `<select>` element dynamically. C# code is doing nothing, but I used the jQuery prepend method to do so and it adds the value; but it does not show up when the page loads. Instead of that the first value that it gets from the database is displayed first. This is my code to retrieve data from database, and I am calling it at page load:

```
   public void GetPrograms()
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetPrograms", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "Programs");
            con.Open();
            program.DataSource = ds;
            program.DataValueField = "ProgID";
            program.DataTextField = "ProgName";
            program.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

These are screen shots of the page:

[page loaded without select program option displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uyTy.png)

[select option is there but is not selected by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbM1t.png)

this is jquery code

```
   $("#program").prepend(new Option("Select Program", "0"));
```

Comment: DropDown in asp.net ?

Comment: No I am using the <Select> tag from HTML instead of asp:DropDown , that's why I am getting this issue.

Comment: @KanchanSharma - then how are you getting .DataSource property for your html select element???

Comment: then why are you showing C# code ?

Comment: because I am using runat="server' attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this at server-side itself

```
program.Items.Insert(0, "Select Program");
```

**Update** As OP wants to do it from Client side:

```
<select id="program">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("select#program").prepend("<option value='0'>Select</option>");
  $("select#program").val("0");
  //alert($('option').length);
});
```

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wj00esyz/

Comment: I have already tried it, but no success. Even it doesn't added it to the list

Comment: saw your comment that you are using html Select...wondering how your other values are getting populated in the dropdown...

Comment: see the code that I have pasted in my question, it is getting populated

Comment: @KanchanSharma - Glad I helped. Please mark as answer if this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Also add

```
program.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

after inserting the "Select Program" to get it selected.